# Grafana not displaying World Map. (grafana-worldmap-panel)

Tags: grafana, world-map

I don't have Internet connection on my terminal (OS-Ubuntu). Therefore I copied 'grafana-worldmap-panel' plugins from other terminal which has OS fedora in folder /var/lib/grafana/plugins/. And restarted grafana server

When I am adding world-map in panel it is showing only Legends, Zoom In Zoom Out buttons and copy right texts in panel. Not showing map. Even when I mouse over pannel mouse pointer turns into "Hand" but not displaying "World-Map"

Any Idea what causing this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have an Internet connection then Worldmap will not work.

Worldmap needs an internet connection to reach a [tile map server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_web_map) so that it can show the map and to be able to zoom in. The plugin uses a free service from [CartoDB](https://github.com/grafana/worldmap-panel/blob/master/src/worldmap.js#L7) which is based on the maps from OpenStreetMap.

If you really, really need the Worldmap plugin, are a programmer and have some free time then you could try implementing an offline mode for Worldmap.

A more in-depth discussion about adding an offline capability to Worldmap can be found in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/grafana/worldmap-panel/issues/48).

Comment: Seems to me like URL we use as parameters is block on my server. I can get it unblock that's not an issue. But URL contains variables too such as {s}, {z} etc.. what url should I use to unblock ? 

I also have downloaded ".mbtiles" file how can I use it to make worldmap-panel work with grafana ?

Comment: I edited my answer to be clearer. Sorry if I wasted your time but unless you are prepared to set up your own tile map server (a lot of work) or build an offline mode for Worldmap (also a lot of work) then you will not be able to get the plugin to work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your support Daniel. I'm finally getting some direction. Definitely the issue is with certain URL that are fetching map tiles and those are not allowed on my server. I can get it done but which URL's to add in list ? "https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" contains a variables. Can you help me out with this ?

Comment: I'm not in front of a computer at the moment. So off the top of my head, x and y are the map coordinates, z is the zoom level (1-16) and s is the subdomain (a,b,c,d)

Comment: Okay I guess allowing "https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net" on server should work s = a,b,c,d.  what you think ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Just checked the code and we use four sub domains - a, b, c and d.